# MySQL SELECT Syntax without reapeting the other value

Tags: mysql, sql, select, syntax, unique

I have this table.

[image: table]

what I want is to only get 1 and 2 only

I have tried :

```
SELECT table_no
from customer_order
where status='true'
```

Comment: please don't use images

Comment: if you can use distinct then use it

Comment: The query you havew should have returned just the column table_no. Maybe you want to add a group by clause?

Comment: try : **string activeTable = "SELECT table_no from customer_order where status='true' GROUP BY table_no ;";**

Comment: string rowCount = "SELECT DISTINCT table_no from customer_order where menu_status='processing' order by table_no desc;"; 

thanks guys I have tried distinct and it worked

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `distinct` keyword:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_no
from customer_order
where status='true'
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of values and limit them to just one of each value, use the group by clause:

```
SELECT table_no
from customer_order
where status='true'
GROUP BY `table_no`
```

Comment: Surely `distinct` is what’s called for here, as per [Mureinik’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51210868)

Comment: @Bohemian, maybe, but group by is more useful, especially if the OP ends up wanting other columns from the table later.

Comment: incorrect. If OP wants other columns from table, `distinct` not only works but is the cannonical solution. Only if *aggregate* values are needed should groups be introduced.